# Qt Bluetooth bonded devices

Tags: qt, bluetooth, qtbluetooth

I would like to connect to already bonded bluetooth device.

Is there a way in Qt Bluetooth that returns List of bonded devices like function [getBondedDevices](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#getBondedDevices) in android studio? Or do I have to scan through all of bluetooth devices and check if the device is already paired like in [Bluetooth Scanner Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtbluetooth-btscanner-example.html) by Qt where they firstly discover all available devices and then check if they are paired:

```
void DeviceDiscoveryDialog::addDevice(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo &info)
{
    const QString label = info.address().toString() + u' ' + info.name();
    const auto items = ui->list->findItems(label, Qt::MatchExactly);
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(label);
        <strong>QBluetoothLocalDevice::Pairing pairingStatus = localDevice->pairingStatus(info.address());</strong>
        item->setForeground(colorForPairing(pairingStatus));
        ui->list->addItem(item);
    }
}
```

Where QBluetoothDeviceInfo is info of newly discovered device:

```
discoveryAgent = new QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent();
connect(discoveryAgent &QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::deviceDiscovered, this, &DeviceDiscoveryDialog::addDevice);
```